# Doing sudo su with ssh on a remote server not working

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, su

This seems to be a popular question on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working for me

I will explain my problems first and then go the the solutions I have tried

What I need to do is to `ssh` to `serverB` from `serverA`. for this I have set up an rsa encryption on the servers and I can successfully ssh to serverB

I use

```
ssh user@hostname
```

Now I want execute certain commands on `serverB`. The first one is to switch to `app` user. For this I need to run `sudo su - app` command but I also want to provide the password in the same line so that it doesnt prompt for the password again.

So I have tried to first directly run `sudo su - app` command on `serverB` with password to test it out

I have tried the following

```
echo "password" | sudo su - app

sudo -S  <<< "password" su - app

echo "password" | sudo -S su - app

echo 'passowrd' | sudo 'su -c - app'
```

However none of the above solutions work for me.

The closest I could get was with

```
echo "password" | script -c "sudo su - app"
```

where it accepts the password and shows me

```
app@hostname [/app]
$
```

however when I run the command `whoami` it still shows me `user` instead of `app`. however when I directly run `sudo su - app` and the provide pass and then run `whoami` it gives me `app`

I am trying to run command with ssh like

```
ssh user@hostname -t 'echo "password" | script -c "sudo su - app"'
```

**P.S.**  the user `user` doesnt have `root` access and also I cannot make use of any plugin as I don't have permission to do the same

My server is `Redhat 6.2`

I hope I could explain it properly. Looking for some answers that can help.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks for help.

Comment: so user is not in ```sudousers``` group?

Comment: @МартинБее no it is not

Comment: if you don`t have root privileges, in my opinion you will not be able to run any command beginning with ```sudo```, if you can, try to login as ```app``` in the beginning with ssh command.

Comment: @МартинБее As I said user has permission to switch to app user. Since when I try sudo su - app and enter password it works

Comment: @МартинБее I have tried that too, but the thing is that I dont have the password for app user and hence I can't login.It would have been really easy if it was possible

Comment: You should probably be using `sudo -u app -i ` and add the relevant `sudoers` entries to not prompt for a password. (Hmm... no root... `sudo su - app` should not work wither...)

With an unpatched RHEL 6.2 box (Redhat 6.2 was released in 2000, so I'm assuming RHEL) there might be privilege escalation exploits... (Assuming it is your own server)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg The thing is, in my organization I have been given a user that has restricted permissions, so it is allowed a few sudo permissions but not all, so I am allowed to do `sudo su - app` but not `sudo su`  or `sudo apt-get install jq` and I wont be able to edit the sudoers file

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: That is not an especially nice method to switch users... You might be able to script it using something like expect... (My previous comment was edited when I noticed the no-root part)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg I have looked at that too but does expect need to installed, if yes i can't do that too

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: the `askpass` option seems like something to look into... (`-S` is the other option, which you tried...) (askpass seems to require an executable to output the password) Another method might be to script the SSH session from the source server, where options like expect might be available...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg Thanks I will try those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set up ssh using rsa key encryption then we don't need to use the password.

In order to enable ssh with public/private key I follow

1. Genrate the `public/private ke`y for user on `serverA`

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```
2. Go to `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file and copy the public key
3. Login to `ServerB` and then do `sudo su - app` to change to app user. Here in the file `.ssh/authorized_key` copy the public key.
4. Try `ssh` to `serverB`  now from `serverA` like

   ```
   ssh app@hostnameServerB
   ```

It works without asking for a password.